# Ruby's factor method explanation

Tags: ruby

```
class Integer
  def factors
    1.upto(Math.sqrt(self)).select {|i| (self % i).zero?}.inject([]) do |f, i| 
      f << self/i unless i == self/i
      f << i
    end.sort
  end
end
[45, 53, 64].each {|n| puts "#{n} : #{n.factors}"}
```

In the above Ruby's code. It is a method to find all factors of an integer. There are several places where I am not too sure about the syntax of.

1. `inject([])` - I have seen `inject(:+)` and `inject(:*)` where it is to add / multiply back into the result. I wonder if this is to push this into the existing array? What's the best way to explain this method?
2. after the `inject([])` there is a `do |f,i|` block. I am not too sure if the `i` is different from the `i` declared outside the block. I assume not? and I am not too sure about what is block is trying to achieve.
3. `end.sort`, Haven't seen it before.

Would be grateful to have advice on this block of code! Thanks!

Comment: 1. What *specifically* is unclear about the documentation of `Enumerable#inject`? 2. Blocks create a lexical scope, so, yes, the `i` in the inner block is different from the one in the outer block. 3. You can call a method on the result of the method without having to assign it to a variable first. You will often see `gets.chomp`, for example, which is calling the `Kernel#gets` method which returns a `String` and then calls `String#chomp` on the return value of the `Kernel#gets` method.

Comment: Please note: if you have three questions, please ask three questions, not one. That way each question can be answered individually. For example, your question #3 has actually been asked many many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `my_array.inject(&:+)` is the same as `my_array.inject(0) do |a, b| a + b end`
   The first `a` will be `0`, and the first `b` will be the first element of `my_array`
2. The inside `i` is set by the inject method and is not the same identifier as the external `i`. inject will do something like `yield(current_value, self[current_index])` and these will be your `|f,i|`
3. In `end.sort`, `end` is the end of the `inject` method call, so it returns a sorted list from the list `inject` returns.

Comment: What about in the ([]) case? Thanks

Comment: if you specify a parameter to inject, it will use it as the first value of `f`; in this case it's [], and then it << things to it.